# How to prevent crontab from executing simultaneously?

Tags: python, cron

I have configured a web scraper, that scrapes a website for live soccer matches being played. The scraper runs every 20 minutes through a cron and takes about 1-2min to scrape each game. Once a game is scraped, its game link is added to a "blacklist" JSON file so it does not get scraped again.

This works fine at times when there are only few games going on simultaneously. On days like Saturday or Sunday there may be so many games simultaneously, that the program cannot catch up anymore and scraping the games takes longer than 30 minutes so that already a new browser opens before the other session has concluded.

Eventually that leads to 7+ browsers being open, some of them even scraping the same game, and the whole thing crashing..

How can I structure this better, so that this cannot occur? Setting the cronjob to less frequently than every 30m is not an option, I would actually like to set it more frequently to every 5m.

I have tried the following crontabs, none of them seem to work in order to actually block the script if the script is already running:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /var/cron.lock  /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Oddsportal/oddsarranger_func_v5_rules_live.py >> /home/pi/Desktop/Oddsportal/log.txt 2>&1

*/30 * * * * run-one /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Oddsportal/oddsarranger_func_v5_rules_live.py

* * * * * root (/usr/bin/pgrep -f /home/pi/Desktop/Oddsportal/oddsarranger_func_v5_rules_live.py || /home/pi/Desktop/Oddsportal/oddsarranger_func_v5_rules_live.py)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to check for already running processes.  You could parse the output of `ps` or you could store a process id in `tmp` folder or database. If it exists, don't fully startup a second process. You'll need proper cleanup code in case of failures.

Comment: @forgetso how would a code/crontab doing this check look like? I am a bit lost here

Comment: You would write the code in your python script (oddsarranger_func_v5_rules_live.py). Something like `>>> f = Path('/tmp/oddschecker').open()
>>> f.readlines()
[]`. If there was a PID present then it would indicate that another process was running. Remove the number from the file (or delete the file) when the process ends or dies.